# Unable to amend dataframe column format from YYYY-MM-DD to DD/MM/YYYY using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe

Struggling with this one. I have pulled a `date` (YYYY-MM-DD) format field from sql server into a data frame using Python (data type now `object`). I would like to amend this column in the data frame to DD/MM/YYYY (I don't mind if the data type becomes a string), but I can't get it to work.

I tried:

```
df['Policy Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Policy Date'], format='%d%m%Y')
```

But got the below error:

> ValueError: time data '2021-04-01' does not match format '%d%m%Y' (match)

I tried amending it first in the sql server script that pulls the data into the data frame:

```
convert(char(10), [Policy Date], 103)
```

Python/sql is giving me the error:

> DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (241) (SQLFetch)')

Edit:

```
df['Policy Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Policy Date'], format='%YYYY-%mm-%dd')
df['Policy Date'] = df['Policy Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%dd/%mm/%YYYY'))
```

Gives me:

> ValueError: time data '2021-04-01' does not match format '%YYYY-%mm-%dd' (match)

Comment: The issue is in your phrase *column format*. A column does not have a format. It has a datatype, which in this case is datetime. You can format it on output, but you can't override how pandas stores it.

Comment: Thank you @BoarGules, formatting on output would work. As the end game would be to extract the df into Excel.

Comment: Sorry @BoarGules do you have any advice on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line of code

```
df['Policy Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Policy Date'], format='%d%m%Y')
```

the **format** parameter specifies the *current* format of the object type column you want transform to datetime type. Then this parameter's value should be **'%Y-%m-%d'**.

After having a datetime type column you can change it's format to the one you need by using

```
import datetime 

df['Policy Date'] = df['Policy Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Comment: Thank you. What does the ```lambda x``` do? Ideally I just want the date in the column not the time :)

Comment: A lambda function is a small anonymous function. It applies the function specified after ":" to the parameters specified before ":" (in this case the only parameter is "x", which in turn represents every value contained in the column "Policy Date"). The function is already specified to not include the time.

Comment: tried that and am getting the error shown in my updated question. What do you think?

Comment: Try 

     df['Policy Date'] = df['Policy Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))

Comment: This is what worked for me: ```df['Policy Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Policy Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')``` and then ```df['Policy Inception Date'] = df['Policy Inception Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))``` If you amend your answer I will accept it. Thanks again for your help. Thanks so much.

Comment: Nice to hear that. I already fixed my answer, you are welcome.